# C# Get embedded resources from specific folder or distinguish between embedded resources in different folders

Tags: c#, reflection, embedded-resource

The title sums it up pretty well.  I know I can get the embedded resource names using:

```
        var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string[] files = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames();
```

But I'd like to be able to get the embedded resources from only a specific folder.  Or at least be able to distinguish between embedded resources from different folders.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The resources are returned in the following format.

```
[Namespace].[Folder].[Filename]
```

Note that all folders in the path are separated by `.`'s. So if you had an embedded resource with the following configuration

```
myproject.csproj (Namespace = com.mycompany.myproject)
- Resources
  - Images
    - Icons
      - my_icon.ico
```

The resource name would be...

```
com.mycompany.myproject.Resources.Images.Icons.my_icon.ico
```

If you want to select all from a specific folder, you could use the following LINQ expression or modify it according to your needs.

```
string prefix = "your_namespace.your_folder."

var resourceNames = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetManifestResourceNames()
    .Where(name => name.StartsWith(prefix));
```

Comment: This code will throw an error because it can't convert IEnumerable to string. Besides it doesn't account for more than one file under the same folder

Comment: Oops, pasted that code from another project and forgot to modify the type. I have corrected it now.

Comment: This find all files in folder including subfolders! Further, if you had embedded file `Res/my.special.file.txt` and you searched for all files within `Res/my/` it would be returned as well.

Comment: It would be helpful to note that if your folder had a hyphen in the name, that gets 'converted' to an underscore for the resource name. I was bashing by head against my desk until I came here and used `GetManifestResourceNames`.

Comment: This give me:
cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Reflection.Assembly'

Answer (score 4):

If you create a folder called Images, and place the file there, then the name of the resource becomes Assembly.Images.fileName.

So you can try something like:

```
var assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();

var names = assembly.GetManifestResourceNames().Where (n => n.Contains(".Images."));
```